# Защита роутов vue3 + firebase

Tags: vue.js, firebase, vue-router

У меня есть пачка роутов

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import firebase from 'firebase'

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'login',
        meta: {layout: 'empty'},
        component: () => import('@/views/LoginPage.vue')
    },
    {
        path: '/register',
        name: 'register',
        meta: {layout: 'empty'},
        component: () => import('@/views/RegisterPage.vue')
    },
  {
    path: '/main',
    name: 'home',
        meta: {layout: 'main', auth: true},
    component: () => import('@/views/MainPage.vue')
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})
```

Я пытаюсь прописать код ниже

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next)=>{
  const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  const requireAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.auth);
  if(requireAuth && !currentUser){
    next({name:'signIn'})
  }else{
    next();
  }
});
```

В итоге я получаю ошибку `Cannot find module 'firebase'`
Я работал по старой статье, где так импортировать было OK.
 На данный момент появилась новая документация, где нужно импортить таким образом `import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';`. Но проблема в том, что я все равно получаю ошибку `[Vue Router warn]: Unexpected error when starting the router: ReferenceError: firebase is not defined`.
 А при попытке вместо firebase прописать initializeApp я получаю ошибку связанную с auth. Устанавливал firebase через `npm install firebase` Если кто-то знает как это переписать под новую доку, буду сильно благодарен.

Comment: Попробуйте  импортить ещё firebase/auth